# Maintaining order of items in the map function: Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am trying to use the map to change the one of the field name , but I see the order of items are getting changed .

```
var arrOfObj = [
  {
    name: "test1",
    value: "value1"
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    value: "value2"
  }
];

function changeKeyName(arr, oldValue, newVal) {
  return arr.map(item => {
    item[`${newVal}`] = item[`${oldValue}`];
    delete item[`${oldValue}`];
    return item;
  });
}

console.log(changeKeyName(arrOfObj, "name", "type"));
```

Is there any way I can maintain the order of items along with changing of one of the field names.

O/P:

`[{type:"test1",value: "value1"}, {type: "test2", value:"value2"}]`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot reproduce. `test1`  stays the first item in the array and `test2` stays the second.

Comment: Also your "O/P" is missing a `},{` between the two objects

Comment: You cannot set the order of object keys.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Sure you can - ES2020 [makes it official](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444013), and environments have had deterministic property order for many years anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` to take an array of entries, then map them, replacing the old key with the new key when found:

```js
var arrOfObj = [
  {
    name: "test1",
    value: "value1"
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    value: "value2"
  }
];

const changeKeyName = (arr, oldKey, newKey) => arr.map(
  item => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(item).map(
      ([key, val]) => [key === oldKey ? newKey : key, val]
    )
  )
);
console.log(changeKeyName(arrOfObj, "name", "type"));
```

(Contrary to popular belief, object property order *is* guaranteed [by the specification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444013), and has been implemented in all environments for years. But keep in mind that this will only work for keys which *aren't* array indicies - array indicies like `0` `1` `2` can't be ordered relative to other properties, they'll always be iterated over first, in ascending numeric order)

That said, code is generally easier to understand if it's written such that property order doesn't matter - if you have code that depends on the properties being in a particular order, I'd recommend refactoring it so that the property order doesn't matter.

Comment: Except for not modifying the original item, this doesn't really change anything in comparison to the OPs code?

Comment: OP's problem is that his `delete` is removing the `name` property from the *first* property in the object and replacing it with a `type` property which is put as the *second* property of the object. He wants `{ type: someVal, value: someVal }`, not `{ value: someVal, type: someVal }`

Comment: @epascarello That only works if `name` is known in advance to be the first property in the object (otherwise, property order gets lost)

Comment: Whoops, I meant to stick that on the OP question, not your answer. lol

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh. In that case, he shouldn't be using objects at all.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I get this when I try integrating,Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.Any idea?

Comment: @li97 You must be using an old IDE or environment that doesn't support `fromEntries` - use [a polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polyfill-object.fromentries).

Answer (score 0):

`map` is being used incorrectly here as you should always return a new set of results from that.

You can do this and you can change the order as required:

```
const arrOfObj = [
  {
    name: "test1",
    value: "value1"
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    value: "value2"
  }
];

function changeKeyName(arr, oldValue, newVal) {
  return arr.map(({ [oldValue]: val, ...rest }) => {
    return {
      [newVal]: val,
      ...rest,
    };
  });
}

console.log(changeKeyName(arrOfObj, "name", "type"));
```

Comment: This does not result in the property order of the replaced object being maintained, which is the main problem OP is concerned with - you're hard-coding the new property at the start of the object. You also need to use a computed property for `newVal`